# Merge and reduce a set of coincident polylines

Tags: javascript, mapping

I have code to find a set of polylines from an input of a list of segments,
Moly is a multiple polyline group that I can Add to other ones, then call "reduce" to make the lines as long as possible.

```
segments=[
 ['AxAy','BxBy']
 ['BxBy','CxCy']
...
 ['LxLy','MxMy']
 ['NxNy','MxMy']

 ['QxQy','RxRy']
 ['RxRy','SxSy']
```

]

```
var moly= new Moly([segments.shift()])
segments.map(segment=>moly.Add(new Moly(segment))
moly.reduce()
        
moly,polylines will be in this case. 
[
  ['AxAy','BxBy','CxCy'...'LxLy','MxMy','NxNy']
  ['QxQy','RxRy','SxSy']
]
```

More complex inputs have various potential outcomes. My code produces a good enough set, it doesnt need to be the optimal network with longest possible lines, just fast. I am calling this very heavily and it's obviously a very classical problem. Is there a classical algorithm or better still some javascript ready to run to do this.
Here is some code. I'm still testing it.

```
function Poly(polylines){

    this.polylines=[]
    for (i=0;i<polylines.length;i++)
        this.Add(polylines[i])

    return this
}

Poly.prototype.Add=function (polyline){
    this.polylines.push(polyline.map(JSON.stringify))
}

Poly.prototype.Reduce=function(){
    for (var i=0;i<this.polylines.length;i++){
        this.polylines=this.polylines.sort((a,b)=>b.length - a.length)
        for (var j=i+1;j<this.polylines.length;j++)
            this.Improve(i,j)
    }
    this.polylines=this.polylines.filter(p=>p.length>0)
}

Poly.prototype.Draw=function(){
    return this.polylines.map(polyline=>polyline.map(JSON.parse))
}


Poly.prototype.Improve=function(I,J){
    var a=this.polylines[I]
    var b=this.polylines[J]
    for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        if (a[i]===b[0] || a[i]===b[b.length-1]){

            if (a[i]===b[b.length-1])
                b.reverse()
            if (i===0)
                a.reverse()
            if (i===0 || i===a.length-1){
                a.pop()
                this.polylines[I]=a.concat(b)
                this.polylines[J]=[]
                return true
            }

            if (i-1+b.length > a.length){
                this.polylines[I]=a.slice(0,i-1).concat(b)
                this.polylines[J]=a.slice(i)
                return true
            }
            if (a.length-i-1+b.length > a.length){
                this.polylines[I]=b.reverse().concat(a.slice(i+1))
                this.polylines[J]=a.slice(0,i+1)
                return true
            }  
        }
    
    return false
}
                
module.exports=Poly
```

Comment: `some javascrpt ready to run to do this` so ... a library?

Comment: I will append my own code if there's no acceptable answer once i;ve gone through all this again. it's not really fit for human consumption as it stands.